# Weblogic hot deployment during development (like WSSD/RAD)

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, weblogic

All my previous projects were on websphere. I am right now in a team developing an application on weblogic.

In Websphere development (WSSD/RAD) the server was more "integrated" with the IDE, so a build could automatically trigger an incremental deployment to the (development/local) server.

Is such a setup possible in a weblogic environment? I googled for some weblogic plugins for eclipse, but I dont see this mentioned as a feature.

What is the best setup for development on weblogic+eclipse, so that the build/deploy/restart overhead is minimal during development?

Comment: If you don't mind changing the IDE, you can use JDeveloper or Netbean. They both have integration with weblogic.

Comment: @khue I will not be change the IDE. A team is already developing on eclipse, and changes would need some change-of-midsets, not to mention the level of approvals. So I am looking at an eclipse option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WebLogic `ant` task for redeploying an application. I'm using this from a command-line `build.xml` as a separate 'redeploy' target, under WLS 9.2, but it can be added to Eclipse's build quite easily I think:

```
<!-- Redeploy the application to WebLogic Server -->
<wldeploy
    action="redeploy" verbose="true" name="<application name>"
    user="<admin user>" password="<admin password>"
    adminurl="t3://<admin server URL>" targets="<server name>" />
```

`<server name>` might be a managed server, or could be your admin server, depending on your configuration.

If you're using sessions and are going to be redeploying frequently, you may find it helpful add a `persistent-store-type` to your `weblogic.xml` to allow sessions to span redeploys, if you aren't doing so already - but as so often, depends what you're doing with your application.

Edited to add link to [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/wldeploy.html)